# Closure called in multiple classes?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, cllocation

I have created a location manager class which get location of user device. Here I have used two closures success and failure. I use this closure in multiple classes. But issue is if I use closure in one class then closure in other class also getting called.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        static let shared = LocationManager()

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        /// This is the clouser that will return the current Address through google login in
        var success: (_ addrees: CLLocation) -> Void = { _ in }

        /// This clouser will return the error
        var failure: Failure = { _ in }

        //MARK: - Permission Checks
        internal var isEnabled: Bool {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse: return true
            default: return false
            }
        }

        private var notDetermined: Bool {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined: return true
            default: return false
            }
        }

        func start() -> Void {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy =  kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            if isEnabled {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else if notDetermined {
                request()
            } else {
                failure(DIError.locationPermissionDenied)
            }
        }
        func request() -> Void {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        //MARK:Location Manager Delegate
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            if let currentLocation: CLLocation = manager.location {
                self.success(currentLocation)
            }else {
                self.failure(DIError.locationPermissionDenied)
            }
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.delegate = nil

        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            failure(DIError.unKnowError())
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                // If status has not yet been determied, ask for authorization
                request()
                break
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                // If authorized when in use
                manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
                break
            case .authorizedAlways:
                // If always authorized
                manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
                break
            case .restricted: failure(DIError.locationPermissionDenied)
            // If restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
                break
            case .denied:
                failure(DIError.locationPermissionDenied)
                // If user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
                break
            }
        }
}
```

Closure used in class for checking if location is available or not

```
 LocationManager.shared.start()
                LocationManager.shared.success = { location in
                        _ = LocationManager.shared.getAddressFromLocation(location: location, completion: { (address) in
                            Utility.shared.saveLocation(objCLLocatin: location.coordinate,address: address)

                        })
                }

                LocationManager.shared.failure = {
                    DILog.print(items: "Failed location")
                    if $0.code == .locationPermissionDenied {
                        self.showPlacePicker()
                        return
                    } else {
                        Utility.shared.showNAlert(titleStr: $0.title, messageStr: $0.message, actionStr: ["Ok".localized], tag: "")
                        DILog.print(items: "other denied")
                    }
                }
```

Failure closure is called for other class also if I am checking location in another class. So the one closure called for multiple classes.

**EDIT:**
I have two classes class A & class B. I fetch location on first controller & check accordingly success and failure block is called.
I push from first controller to second controller then I again check for current location.So if on second controller ie. B.So if failure block is called for second controller then also it is called for first controller.
I am surprised why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior if you are using singleton class for multiple class, the closure will get overwrite everytime u set `success = ...`, and only the last one is called, and its the one have been set on the last class, not the current class that using the closure

Either remove singleton (create different instance for each class) or use something like dictionary-based handler (example ["ClassName": successClosure]), this is same as delegate, if use delegate then also have to overwrite each time you change your handling class

Comment: Disagree with this suggestion. For what reason singleton that is used by multiple classes and have single reference to successor closure will remember all assignees and call them every time you perform failure()?
failure closure that was assigned last will be called.

Comment: I think this is unclear.  If you have a singleton class with a success and failure closures then only the last one of each will be held.  Now any other references held to those closures will remain but they will not be called only the latest one of each will.  Other than that the rest of if is valid either separate instances or an array/dictionary of handlers would work.

Comment: I think i have described it a bit wrong, the Closure will be overwrite, and only the last one is called, and its the one have been set on the last class, not the current class that using the Closure, use dictionary is what im doing with this situation( using the exact same thing with keyboard handling closure based on different class)